# subtraction from multiple tables - sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Im doing a few exersices for the my head around SQL queries. Im trying to achieve all items( partno) that haven't been ordered. This is a below diagram[image]

What im trying to achieve is the Full List of partno's from the parts table minus the Partno from the OrderedItems Table. I beleive i would need to do a Left Outter Join.

Like Below

```
SELECT *
FROM PARTS, ORDEREDITEMS
LEFT OUTER JOIN ordereditems.Partno - parts.Partno;
```

Still a bit stuck on this one, is this the right track on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from parts 
where partno not in ( select partno from ordereditems)
```

Simply select all that are not in the other table.

```
select * 
from parts 
where not exists ( select 1 from ordereditems where partno = parts.partno)
```

would be an alternate way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks, Worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

```
select Parts.*
from Parts left join Ordereditem
on Parts.partno = Ordereditem.partno
where Ordereditem.partno is null
```

Comment: We have a winner, folks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select a.partno - b.partno from
(select * from PARTS) as a
left JOIN
(select * from ORDEREDITEMS) as b
on a.Partno = b.Partno
```

Comment: you can add the other field using `a.fields and b.fields`

Comment: the important here is you know the foriegn key and the primary key of each and every table like on `a.id = b.id`